# Как использовать web-кнопки в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Люди профессионалы, помогите, как делать. :(

Comment: Что такое web-кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Могу еще порекомендовать [**AlphaSkins**](http://www.alphaskins.com/index_rus.php)

Answer (score 0):

Либо скачать специальный компонент, либо с помощью `TImage`. Всё просто. Удачи)

Answer (score 0):

Проще свой компонент написать. Проработать 4-е состояния: `Enabled, Disabled, Hot, Pressed`. И вешать на эти состояния `TImage`.